# NLP model training

Tags: nlp, octave, weka, opennlp

I just started with NLP (Natural Language Processing) and struggling to understand one important concept. How to train system for relation extraction on future inputs?

For example, I have few lines like:

- Tom is working for abc company
- Jerry works at xyz
- organization is the  place where Person works.

In all these cases relation ship is "person" "Organization" with relation ship type "working"

Based on above examples and some NLP readings, I think we need to train system based on Part of Speech tag than real "entity names", to make it generic for other input data in field. This is the part I am really confused.

Please don't simply point me to some algorithms( SVM etc.,), because I know it is possible with them, but I am missing details on how algorithms process these lines to process other inputs. All the examples I see directly provides models and tells use them, due to which I am unable to construct few things I would like to.

Any example on how algorithms (any example algorithm is Ok) use above sentences to construct training model would be really helpful.

Thank you for your time and help.

Note: Any one of the programming language specified in tags section is Ok for me.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you mean by 'NLP'. I'm guessing you mean Natural Language Processing?

Comment: @NathanCraike: Yes, Natural Language Processing.It seems there is no tag with "Natural Language Processing", so had to use NLP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct.  There are so many words that simply using the word won't actually allow you to develop a good model.  You need to reduce the dimensionality.  As you suggested, one way to do that is to take the part of speech.  Of course, there are also other features that you could extract. For example, the following very small portion of one of my .arff files was used for determining whether a period in a sentence marked the end of or not:

```
@relation period

@attribute minus_three {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute minus_three_length real
@attribute minus_three_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute minus_two {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute minus_two_length real
@attribute minus_two_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute minus_one {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute minus_one_length real
@attribute minus_one_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute plus_one {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute plus_one_length real
@attribute plus_one_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute plus_two {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute plus_two_length real
@attribute plus_two_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute plus_three {'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'NP', 'PDT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP','WRB', 'NUM', 'PUNC', 'NEND', 'RAND'}
@attribute plus_three_length real
@attribute plus_three_case {'UC','LC','NA'}
@attribute left_before_reliable real
@attribute right_before_reliable real
@attribute spaces_follow_period real
@attribute class  {'EOS','NEOS'}

@data

VBP, 2, LC,NP, 4, UC,NN, 1, UC,NP, 6, UC,NEND, 1, NA,NN, 7, LC,31,47,1,NEOS
NNS, 10, LC,RBR, 4, LC,VBN, 5, LC,?, 3, NA,NP, 6, UC,NP, 6, UC,93,0,0,EOS
VBD, 4, LC,RB, 2, LC,RP, 4, LC,CC, 3, UC,UH, 5, LC,VBP, 2, LC,19,17,2,EOS
```

EDIT (based off of question):
So, this was a supervised learning experiment.  The training data came from normal sentences in a paragraph style format, but were transformed to the following vector model:

- Column 1: Class: End-of-Sentence or Not-End-of-Sentence
- Columns 2-8: The +/- 3 words surrounding the period in question
- Columns 9,10: The number of words to the left/right, respectively, of the period before the next reliable sentence delimiter (e.g. ?, ! or a paragraph marker).
- Column 11: The number of spaces following the period.

Of course, this is not a very complicated problem to solve, but it's a nice little introduction to Weka.  Since we can't just use the words as features, I used their POS tags.  I also extracted length of words, whether or not the word was capitalized, etc.

So, you could feed anything as testing data, so long as you're able to transform it into the vector model above and extract the features used in the .arff.

Comment: +1. Thanks! if I understand correctly you have created all possible values for each feature (attributes) and data section has training data for different combinations. Can you please explain an example English sentence and how this training file will be used for that purpose? What I am trying to do is extracting relationship between words in sentence.

Comment: Are you trying to do unsupervised or supervised learning?  If you don't have class labels for your data, then you'll be doing unsupervised learning (not the example that I did above).  For unsupervised data, you can use several clustering algorithms available in Weka: such as K-means, EM, Cob-web, Meta-Clusterer. From these, you will be able to group individual sentences into clusters, which should hopefully group similar sentences together.  For what you want to do, if you just use the POS tags, you won't be able to highlight the relationship as :x WORKS at y.

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem.  Dealing with syntax is one thing, but trying to derive meaning and group based off of syntax and semantics is a whole other ballgame. Text classification is tough, I think.

Comment: Yes, thanks Steve, these are some valuable inputs and clarified some issues. Good luck with your PhD

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Good lucky with your project.